# Open Source Projects for Web Search Engine Components

Tags: open-source, search-engine

Can someone put a list of open source software of each of these components included in the question ["Building a web search engine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112248/building-a-web-search-engine)?

That will save many people's time in the search for high quality open source components.

Component List:

1. Crawler
2. Parser
3. Indexer
4. Ranking Engine
5. Front End

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: Noted and edited the tags. Thanks for asking, TFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Java world:

Parsers

- [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/)
- [Antlr](http://antlr.org)

Indexer

- [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org)

Ranking Engine

- [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org)

Front End

- whatever lightweight MVC framework

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is also available for .NET http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Apache Nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/) does everything you need out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Nutch + Lucene + Mapreduce/Apache is your solution.