# Search Engine and Web Crawler

Tags: api, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build a custom search engine for my project using an API or any related program to this. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: seems similar to this.. why not try search it first here and then check each results if it match to your case. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112248/building-a-web-search-engine

Comment: [Algolia](http://www.algolia.com/) check this out...